# verbose colcon build

Tags: ros, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to print as much information as possible out of colcon, such as CMake, print order of compilation etc. Anyone here has any suggestions? colcon build --help doesnt really say much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395456/verbose-colcon-build/) by [renob321](https://answers.ros.org/users/89122/renob321/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2022-02-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does adding this to your `colcon build` work?

```
--event-handlers console_direct+ --cmake-args -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON
```

---

You could opt for `console_cohesion+` instead of `console_direct+`, if interleaving output is confusing:

```
--event-handlers console_cohesion+ --cmake-args -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON
```

See also [colcon: How To](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/user/how-to.html).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [renob321](https://answers.ros.org/users/89122/renob321/) on 2022-02-01**:
console_cohesion+ looks nice, thanks